# configure a simple (stripped down) desktop environment for xrdp sessions using xfce4

Tags: xfce, window-manager, session, xrdp

I'm building a session server for xrdp remote desktop sessions. I want to run just a browser and an X client program in each remote desktop, so my casual remote-desktop users can perform some specific tasks and then close their sessions.

(I'm planning to present these virtual desktops to users via Apache Guacamole.)

I'd like a desktop session manager environment for these folks without such things as a file manager, a multi-page screen manager. But, I would like to keep enough session manager functionality to allow

- handling of multiple browser windows and app windows, dynamically
- a way to deiconify windows the user iconifies (revealing the icods and letting the user click on them.)

I've tried just running the `xfwm4` window manager, rather than `xfce4-session`, from the .xsession script. While a bit crude, that works OK. But it doesn't present icons for iconized windows.

How can I configure the desktop environment for xfce4 (or another suitable session scheme) to suppress the power user stuff and still give me icons?